# Alignment issue and Bootstrap button modification

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a custom design to make:

[image]

The current implementation looks like :[image]

How can I make the first button named manedlig donation and enkel donation to have that arrow pointer using CSS? Also I am unable to make the same horizontal alignment and they look misaligned.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>demo form</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery UI autocomplete CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" />

    <style>
        /* Overriding Styles */
        .radio-toolbar {
            margin: 10px 0px;
        }

        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
            opacity: 0;
            /* position: fixed; */
            width: 0;
        }

        .radio-toolbar label {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 5px 22px;
            font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }

        .radio-toolbar label:hover {
            background-color: #E7E7E7;
        }

        /* .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
            border: 2px dashed #444;
        } */

        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
            background-color: #C8951C;
            color: white;
            border: none;
        }

        #basic-addon2 {
            background-color: white;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #amount::placeholder {

            /* Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
            text-align: center;
            margin-left: 20px !important;
        }

        input {
            border-radius: 0
        }

        .custom-btn {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-width: 150px;
        }

        .custom-btn span {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .custom-btn-2::before {
            background-color: #C8951C;
            transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        }

        .custom-btn-2 span {
            color: #C8951C;
            border: 1px solid #C8951C;
            transition: 0.2s;
        }

        .custom-btn-2 span:hover {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            background-color: #C8951C;
            transition: 0.2s 0.1s;
        }

        .custom-btn.hover-opacity::before {
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .custom-btn.hover-opacity:hover::before {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #fbf9f7;">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto mt-2">
                <form id="form_submit">
                    <div class="radio-toolbar mb-5">
                        <input type="radio" id="monthly" name="frekvens" value="monthly" checked>
                        <label for="monthly">Månedlig donation</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="one-time" name="frekvens" value="one-time">
                        <label for="one-time">Enkel donation</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-toolbar" id="monthly-donation-block">
                        <input type="radio" id="amount-29" name="monthly-belob" value="29">
                        <label for="amount-29">29 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-49" name="monthly-belob" value="49" checked>
                        <label for="amount-49">49 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-79" name="monthly-belob" value="79">
                        <label for="amount-79">79 DKK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-toolbar" id="one-time-donation-block" style="display: none;">
                        <input type="radio" id="amount-99" name="one-time-belob" value="99">
                        <label for="amount-99">99 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-149" name="one-time-belob" value="149" checked>
                        <label for="amount-149">149 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-199" name="one-time-belob" value="199">
                        <label for="amount-199">199 DKK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control num-only auto-ok" id="belob" placeholder="Valgfrit beløb"
                            aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">DKK</span>
                        <div id="belob-feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                            Incorrect Number
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control num-only" id="phone" placeholder="Telefonnummer" required
                            maxlength="10">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="custom-btn custom-btn-2 hover-opacity">
                            <span>FORTSÆT</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- These two are required unless jQuery & bootstrap is already included -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- This is required for autocomplete api -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.dataforsyningen.dk/dawa/assets/dawa-autocomplete2/1.0.2/dawa-autocomplete2.min.js"></script>
<!-- this is required for debounce delay of input field -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-LGXaggshOkD/at6PFNcp2V2unf9LzFq6LE+sChH7ceMTDP0g2kn6Vxwgg7wkPP7AAtX+lmPqPdxB47A0Nz0cMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.16/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

(Font type can be ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `::after` to create the pointer

```
      .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label.with-pointer::after {
        content: '';
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background: #C8951C;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: translate(-50%, 8px) rotate(
45deg);
      }
```

Also the alignment could be achieve with flex properties on the container:

see full code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>demo form</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery UI autocomplete CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" />

    <style>
        /* Overriding Styles */
        .radio-toolbar {
          margin: 10px 0px;
          display: flex;
        }

        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
            opacity: 0;
            /* position: fixed; */
            width: 0;
        }

        .radio-toolbar label {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 5px 22px;
            font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
            border-radius: 0px;
            flex:1;
            margin-right: 8px;
        }
      
      .radio-toolbar label:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }

        .radio-toolbar label:hover {
            background-color: #E7E7E7;
        }

        /* .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
            border: 2px dashed #444;
        } */

        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
            background-color: #C8951C;
            color: white;
            border: none;
            position: relative;
        }

      .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label.with-pointer::after {
        content: '';
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background: #C8951C;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: translate(-50%, 8px) rotate(
45deg);
      }
      
     
        #basic-addon2 {
            background-color: white;
        }

        input[type="text"] {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #belob::placeholder {

            /* Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
            margin-left: -58px !important;
        }

        input {
            border-radius: 0
        }

        .custom-btn {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            min-width: 150px;
padding: 0px;
        }

        .custom-btn span {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .custom-btn-2::before {
            background-color: #C8951C;
            transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        }

        .custom-btn-2 span {
            color: #C8951C;
            border: 1px solid #C8951C;
            transition: 0.2s;
        }

        .custom-btn-2 span:hover {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            background-color: #C8951C;
            transition: 0.2s 0.1s;
        }

        .custom-btn.hover-opacity::before {
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .custom-btn.hover-opacity:hover::before {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #fbf9f7;">
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto mt-2">
                <form id="form_submit">
                    <div class="radio-toolbar mb-5">
                        <input type="radio" id="monthly" name="frekvens" value="monthly" checked>
                        <label for="monthly" class="with-pointer">Månedlig donation</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="one-time" name="frekvens" value="one-time">
                        <label for="one-time" class="with-pointer">Enkel donation</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-toolbar" id="monthly-donation-block">
                        <input type="radio" id="amount-29" name="monthly-belob" value="29">
                        <label for="amount-29">29 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-49" name="monthly-belob" value="49" checked>
                        <label for="amount-49">49 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-79" name="monthly-belob" value="79">
                        <label for="amount-79">79 DKK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-toolbar" id="one-time-donation-block" style="display: none;">
                        <input type="radio" id="amount-99" name="one-time-belob" value="99">
                        <label for="amount-99">99 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-149" name="one-time-belob" value="149" checked>
                        <label for="amount-149">149 DKK</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="amount-199" name="one-time-belob" value="199">
                        <label for="amount-199">199 DKK</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control num-only auto-ok" id="belob" placeholder="Valgfrit beløb"
                            aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">DKK</span>
                        <div id="belob-feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                            Incorrect Number
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control num-only" id="phone" placeholder="Telefonnummer" required
                            maxlength="10">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="custom-btn custom-btn-2 hover-opacity">
                            <span>FORTSÆT</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- These two are required unless jQuery & bootstrap is already included -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- This is required for autocomplete api -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.dataforsyningen.dk/dawa/assets/dawa-autocomplete2/1.0.2/dawa-autocomplete2.min.js"></script>
<!-- this is required for debounce delay of input field -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-LGXaggshOkD/at6PFNcp2V2unf9LzFq6LE+sChH7ceMTDP0g2kn6Vxwgg7wkPP7AAtX+lmPqPdxB47A0Nz0cMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.16/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: What about the tiny margin gap on left and right side of "FORTSÆT" button?

Comment: @ShihabUllah that seems just something added by the theme/boostrap, can be removed with the .custom-btn. see updated

Comment: Thank you @Yichaoz ! :)

Comment: is there is any way to align the placeholder value of amount field w.r.t the placeholder value "telefonnummer"? I have aligned it middle but I want to have it more margin-left or centrally align with the placeholder value "telefonnummer"

Comment: since there is a DKK (currency)  it's offseted, you can offset the amount placeholder to compensate the same width of the currency. but I have to say it's really hacky, ideally you want everything align to the left of the input

Comment: How can I achieve it. I understand and agree that ideally it should be to the left but now as per design its giving me headache and still trying... Will really appreciate it if you provide this last wave of your magic wand (pray)

Comment: I have update with that alignment offset change. I have to say it's a HACK, NOT RECOMMENDED. because the actual text won't match the placeholder. it depends on the currency width. breaks if the placeholder is same with as the input. you've been warned

Answer (score 0):

For the pointer arrow, you could have it by using CSS border:

```css
button {position:relative; padding:10px; background:orange; color:#fff; border:none;}
button:before {
    content:''; position:absolute; top:100%; left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    border-top:15px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

I'm not sure what "horizontal alignment" you're talking about?

Comment: By horizontal alignment I meant that my custom radio button are squeezed and doesnt take the whole row and I want every rows element to have equal margin on left or right side. Please see this image: https://imgur.com/nvVjeeD

Comment: Also I am using radio button as u can see in the code. How can I apply your CSS for the radio button?

Comment: Use my CSS for the `.radio-toolbar label` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of solution for those requirements. I've made a partial example for the button design. you can check that out.

> styles

```css
    /* Overriding Styles */
.radio-toolbar {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  /* position: fixed; */
  width: 0;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 22px;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.radio-toolbar label:hover {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

/* .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
border: 2px dashed #444;
} */

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #C8951C;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
.btn-color{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #c8951c;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-toolbar mb-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-color">
        <input type="radio" id="monthly" name="frekvens" value="monthly" checked>
        <label for="monthly" class="button-month">
          Månedlig donation
        </label>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/njmsaikat/pen/gOXYzBe